# Trying to understand the nperseg effect of Welch method

Tags: power-spectral-density

I am new in DSP and I like to compute the correct PSD.

I have a 2s signal sampled at 256Hz

[image]

I compute the psd

`freqs, psd = signal.welch(data, fs=256, nperseg=128, scaling='spectrum')`

I chose different nperseg, 128, 256, ... and later more larger data .

I computed the PSD and it is the result:

[image]

If I increase the nperseg length, the PSD decreases (show the Y axis), although in the X axis appears some powers bins, because the frequency resolution increases.

[image]

Also, if I increase the data length, for example to 4 s, the powers in X axis are more noticeable as in the image below.

[image]

My goal is to analyze the behavior of power at different frequencies, so in my opinion large data will provide better results for mi work, however my data samples will be reduced.

**My question is, it is valid to compute PSD overlapping data (for instance data chunk of 2 seconds, but overlapping 1 sec) ?**

Answer (score 3):

A good reference for the performance of Welch's method for Power Spectral Density (PSD) estimation can be found in [this report](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/5688766) by Solomon.

Welch's method involves the averaging of multiple periodograms (PSD estimates) from, potentially overlapping, segments of data. This method is beneficial because the noise from multiple periodograms gets "averaged out," though at a trade-off of decreased frequency resolution from shorter segment lengths. The larger `nperseg` (number of samples per segment) is, the fewer segments or averages you can take and the higher frequency resolution you get. Conversely, the smaller `nperseg` is, the better noise rejection you get but with lower frequency resolution.

As mentioned in the Solomon's report, the noise cancelling effect is most effective when the periodograms being averaged are *independent* of each other. If you select the `noverlap` argument of `signal.welch` to be large (e.g. `nperseg - 1`), two adjacent periodograms will be *highly* correlated and thus not very independent.

From page 8 of Solomon's report:

> Ideally $S$, the number of samples to shift between segments, should be the smallest value such that the $X_k(\nu)$ and $X_{k+1}(\nu)$ are nearly uncorrelated. This value of $S$ would save arithmetic operations but provide the maximum amount of smoothing. The shift between segments, $S$, is usually in the range of $0.4M \le S \le M$.

where $M=$`nperseg` and $X_k(\nu)$ is the discrete Fourier transform value of the $k$th segment. So to answer your question:

> Is it valid to compute PSD overlapping data (for instance data chunk of 2 seconds, but overlapping 1 sec) ?

Yes, it can be valid to perform PSD estimation using overlapping segments. How much overlap between segments you should use depends on how correlated your data is in time. By default, Scipy sets `noverlap=nperseg // 2` because a 50% overlap is commonly employed and is probably sufficient for most problems, but one cannot say that this is necessarily the *ideal* overlap for your case. If you know your data can be modeled as a [moving average model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model), then your largest correlation lag is simply the order of that model.

**If you don't know anything about your data, an overlap of 50% can be a reasonable estimate, but be aware that it is only an estimate and likely differs from the true PSD. The same argument could be made for 0% overlap. Make sure to select a segment length `nperseg` that gives you an adequate frequency resolution for your analysis.**